# Number shown weird, not 2 decimal point

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, laravel-4

Sorry for a weird title I gave....

I am using laravel4.2 to develop and use Chrome to run the program, my colleague shown 46.35 %, but I shown 46.349998474121 %. It supposed to show 2 decimal point.

I try to change the data type to float(5,2), failed.
I try to change the data type to float(24,2), failed.

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ratio" id="ratio" style="text-align:right;" maxlength="5"  value="{{{ Input::old('ratio', isset($mainArray) ? $mainArray->ratio : null) }}}"/>
    </div>%
</div>
```

pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can round the number up with PHP, instead of changing the datatype. Try with `round()`.

```
{{{ Input::old('ratio', isset($mainArray) ? round($mainArray->ratio, 2) : null) }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `number_format`

```
{{{ Input::old('ratio', (isset($mainArray) ? number_format($mainArray->ratio, 2) : null)) }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the exact json or value that you are passing to the view. 
Because wrapping the value in `round($mainArray->ratio, 2)` should do the trick. I myself have used many times. Inorder to get you the exact solution you are looking for I would like to see what format is your data going to view.

Type `return $variable` in controller to find out what you are passing and share here.